# ArgumentException : Format of the initialization string does not confirm to specification starting at index 102

Tags: c#, database, oledbconnection, jet

I'm importing an excel file to the database through datagridview in winforms. I got this exception as I click the "Import Excel File" button. The exception in raising at the line:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

My connectionString is:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\GPS_WTGs.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";
```

In my winform, I have only 1 button and datagridview.

How to handle this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is not well formed, you don't need the extra `"` and the backslashes. You could try the following one:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\GPS_WTGs.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"
```

Comment: @Chistos I made changes in the string as u told but now I'm getting new exception called "Could not find installable ISAM" at the line where I'm opening an Oledb connection which has been created using the previous connectionString as a parameter

Comment: @RitujaNashikkar please have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/209805/you-receive-a-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-message-or-some-fi.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating on Christos's answer, try placing single Quotes on the **Extended Properties**

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\GPS_WTGs.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Readonly=False;';"
```

Or

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\GPS_WTGs.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Readonly=False;';"
```

Comment: new exception now...Cannot update,Database or object is read only..even though user has full permission to access it

Comment: try using provider `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` instead and set Readonly to  False!, updated answer

Comment: Failure connecting file.....what might be the reason behind this exception? And yes the ReadOnly property is false.